# Unable to deploy R model using Rstudio on google cloud platform

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform, rstudio

I am using Rstudio on Google cloud Compute engine and using examples on

[https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/keras/](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/)

My final objective is to be able to deploy R - model to AI platform and get predictions out of it. I have tried many examples using keras,tfestimators,tensorflow but none of them are able to run completely. All of the only run till training but when Its time to export_savemodel() they all fail. Local prediction,evaluation works fine.

```
model %>% evaluate(x_test, y_test) # work fine in Rstudio
model %>% predict_classes(x_test)  # work fine in Rstudio
```

**Want my model version to appear here.**

[image]

Issues:

After completing the training , I am unable to export model to GCS bucket as command for this is failing.

```
 export_savedmodel(model, "savedmodel")
```

**Error message:**

```
Error in export_savedmodel.keras.engine.training.Model(model,"savedmodel") : 
'export_savedmodel()' is currently unsupported under the TensorFlow 
 Keras implementation, consider using 'tfestimators::keras_model_to_estimator()'.
```

Then I changed my code to below but still get error message:

```
library(tfestimators)
tfe_model <- tfestimators::keras_model_to_estimator(model)
export_savedmodel(tfe_model, "savedmodel")
```

Error:

```
 Error in export_savedmodel.tf_estimator(tfe_model, "savedmodel") : 
 Currently only classifier and regressor are supported. Please specify a 
 custom serving_input_receiver_fn.
```

What I need:

How can I fix the issue ?
Or any guidance on how to deploy R packages on Google cloud platform will be appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at this sample notebook? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ml-on-gcp/blob/master/tutorials/R/02-Training-Serving-TF-Models.ipynb

Comment: Thanks , will use it